# combine multiple xtables in R

Tags: r, latex, tex, xtable

I would like to combine 2 dataset, when I run code below in R, however doesn't show the headers and I would like to see the column header for each dataset

```
 iriss <- head(iris)
    iriss1 <- tail(iris)
   print(xtable(rbind(iriss,iriss1)))
```

expected output is this, how can i get this from R console?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrl}
        \hline
        & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
        \hline
        1 & 5.10 & 3.50 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
        2 & 4.90 & 3.00 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
        3 & 4.70 & 3.20 & 1.30 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
        4 & 4.60 & 3.10 & 1.50 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
        5 & 5.00 & 3.60 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
        6 & 5.40 & 3.90 & 1.70 & 0.40 & setosa \\ 
        \hline
        & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
        \hline
        145 & 6.70 & 3.30 & 5.70 & 2.50 & virginica \\ 
        146 & 6.70 & 3.00 & 5.20 & 2.30 & virginica \\ 
        147 & 6.30 & 2.50 & 5.00 & 1.90 & virginica \\ 
        148 & 6.50 & 3.00 & 5.20 & 2.00 & virginica \\ 
        149 & 6.20 & 3.40 & 5.40 & 2.30 & virginica \\ 
        150 & 5.90 & 3.00 & 5.10 & 1.80 & virginica \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Where does `xtable` come from?

Comment: The first part iş coming from R consolote, but i want to get the second part using R consolate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `xtable` is essentially a data frame with a printing method that shows the latex code for reproducing the table in a latex document. It is therefore not possible to create an `xtable` object that prints the way you want it to.

However, it *is* possible to get the desired output to the console by capturing the console output and manipulating it to join multiple tables together. Here is a function that will do it:

```r
multi_xtable <- function(...)
{
  vars <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))[-1]
  df_list <- lapply(vars, eval)
  num_cols <- sapply(df_list, length)
  if (!all(num_cols == num_cols[1]))
    stop("All data frames must have equal number of columns")  
  xtables <- lapply(df_list, function(x) capture.output(xtable::xtable(x)))
  if (length(xtables) == 1) 
    return(xtables[[1]])  
  header <- xtables[[1]][1:6]
  tail <- xtables[[1]][length(xtables[[1]]) + (-1:0)]
  xtables <- lapply(xtables, function(x) x[7:(length(x) - 2)])
  xtables <- do.call("c", xtables)  
  cat(header, xtables, tail, sep = "\n")
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```r
multi_xtable(iriss, iriss1)
#> % latex table generated in R 3.6.2 by xtable 1.8-4 package
#> % Wed Apr 29 12:51:24 2020
#> \begin{table}[ht]
#> \centering
#> \begin{tabular}{rrrrrl}
#>   \hline
#>  & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
#>   \hline
#> 1 & 5.10 & 3.50 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
#>   2 & 4.90 & 3.00 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
#>   3 & 4.70 & 3.20 & 1.30 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
#>   4 & 4.60 & 3.10 & 1.50 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
#>   5 & 5.00 & 3.60 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
#>   6 & 5.40 & 3.90 & 1.70 & 0.40 & setosa \\ 
#>    \hline
#>  & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
#>   \hline
#> 145 & 6.70 & 3.30 & 5.70 & 2.50 & virginica \\ 
#>   146 & 6.70 & 3.00 & 5.20 & 2.30 & virginica \\ 
#>   147 & 6.30 & 2.50 & 5.00 & 1.90 & virginica \\ 
#>   148 & 6.50 & 3.00 & 5.20 & 2.00 & virginica \\ 
#>   149 & 6.20 & 3.40 & 5.40 & 2.30 & virginica \\ 
#>   150 & 5.90 & 3.00 & 5.10 & 1.80 & virginica \\ 
#>    \hline
#> \end{tabular}
#> \end{table}
```